# What is CuCl · CO · 2 H₂O?

Tags: coordination-compounds, transition-metals, applied-chemistry

What is the chemical $\ce{CuCl.CO.2H2O},$ formed via the reaction of copper chloride and carbon monoxide?

Does this compound have any use or appear in any noteworthy reaction?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

Answer (score 7):

The compound is called **copper(I) chloride dihydrate - carbon monoxide adduct**. [It is formed during the Gatterman-Koch reaction](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=4x-GAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA642&lpg=PA642&dq=copper%20chloride%20adduct%20carbon%20monoxide&source=bl&ots=COrB4nClDK&sig=lGpwIWk-mUxQE1kDeqYP3q1ymqQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5vt_kr-bRAhVHLo8KHYkfBhUQ6AEIJDAD#v=onepage&q=copper%20chloride%20adduct%20carbon%20monoxide&f=false).

Gatterman-Koch reaction is a reaction that produces aromatic aldehyde from aromatic hydrocarbons. The reagent used are carbon monoxide, hydrochloric acid and a Friedel-Craft catalyst like copper(I) chloride ($\ce{CuCl}$) or aluminium chloride ($\ce{AlCl3}$). **So, the adduct is formed by the reaction of copper chloride and carbon monoxide during the course of reaction.** If aluminium chloride is used, then a complex would be formed i.e aluminum trichloride complex, $\ce{[HCO(AlCl4)]}$.

To know more about the mechanism and role of reagents, [see this previous question on chem.SE.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58379/gattermann-koch-reaction-role-of-cucl).

**Other References**

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gattermann_reaction
2. https://www3.aiche.org/proceedings/Abstract.aspx?PaperID=358705

Answer (score 2):

By dissolving mixture of ammoniacal cuprous chloride solution  with carbon monoxide, the reaction that occurs is the formation for copper(I) chloride dihydrate carbon monoxide adduct:

$$\ce{CuCl + CO + 2 H2O -> CuCl·CO·2H2O}.$$

This reaction is also used in Bosch process for the removal of carbon monoxide.

Comment: It would be nice if the answer were also backed up by providing the references to the original publication/patent.

Answer (score 0):

$\ce{CuCl.CO.2H2O}$ is the addidtion compound when CO is passed through the ammonical solution of cuprous chloride.

$$\ce{CuCl + CO + 2H2O -> CuCl.CO.2H2O}$$

It is white crystalline adduct.

I dont really know the name... but this is the story behind this compound..

Comment: You're not saying much that OP didn't already say, to be honest. It's not much of your fault; the question is just poor.

Answer (score 0):

We can consider it as coordination compound in which Chlorido and carbonyl acts as ligands and it can be represented as  $\ce{[CuCl(CO)].2H2O}$

Comment: Cu+ is transition metal ion and it form coordination compounds with Lewis bases.